# preparedStatement.setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)

Tags: jdbc

### Question #1

Could you anyone please tell me what is the benefit I will receive using the following code, when `sPhoneExt` is `null` ?

```java
if (sPhoneExt == null || sPhoneExt.trim().equals("")) {
    stmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
} else {
    stmt.setString(9, sPhoneExt);
}
```

Instead of `stmt.setString(9, sPhoneExt);`

Because `iPhoneType = rset.getInt("phone_type");` will return `0` if the value is SQL `NULL`; which I don't want.

---

### Question #2

And just curious `stmt.setString(9, null)` is performed what will be the return of `rset.getInt("phone_type")`?

### Answer #2

`getInt()` will return zero when it is null in DB. You have to use the below code to know about DB `NULL`.

```java
if (rs.wasNull()) {
    // handle NULL field value
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the datatype for *sPhoneExt* in your database? And why're trying use `setString(..)` when storing and `getInt(..)` when you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: It is declared as String in java. NUMBER in DB.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see any benefit using `setNull` in this String case. 
It is only used to check empty string "" and insert null in DB. But for that also we can do it like `stmt.setString(9, null);`

But when sPhoneExt is Integer and holding null, then We cannot perform 
`stmt.setInt(9, sPhoneExt);`  since `setInt(int, int)` API performs; converting (Unboxing) sPhoneExt (Integer) to primitive (int), so you will get NullPointerException. So you are in need of `stmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);`

Finally if you have inserted null in DB for NUMBER (sql type) column; getInt() will return 0 only.

This is irrespective of the below null set mechanism.

```java
stmt.setString(9, null);
stmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
```

Also Somebody told when the DB NUMBER column has default Value; that default value will be consider differently by the above two lines. But that is not true. Even that case also both the above line performs same way. It is setting `NULL` value; not the default value.

```sql
create table t1 (id number default 1 );
insert into t1 (id) values (2);
```

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class TestDB {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.201.32.92:1521:psprd1", "username", "password");
            String query = null;
            String l = null;
            ResultSet rset = null;
            int paramIndex = 1;
            query = "UPDATE t1 " + " SET id = ?";

            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(paramIndex++, null);
            // stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();

            query = "select id from t1 ";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            rset.next();
            System.out.println(rset.getString("id"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}
```